# How to import and rename a series of objects with python

Tags: python, objects, import

I have a scene where you have multiple objects, and want to import and rename them as only `cone1, sphere1, cube1`. I do not want Blender to automatically rename `New_cone_New_cone.025` for example, which is very strange. I want to make it with code in python.

Comment: When you say "import" do you mean from an alien file format (like .OBJ) or link from another .blend file?   What are the rules for renaming?

Answer (score 1):

Without any good rules for renaming I'm going to offer this code snippet as a starting point:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.select:
        obj.name = "bacon"
```

This will rename every selected object to "bacon", although blender will notice that is a duplicate and append suffixes like .001, .002 automatically.

If you need something fancier feel free to add some detail to the question and I'll complicate my answer.

Comment: To an empty scene, I want to import a list of some and different objects to the scene. The file format is .OBJ

Comment: in blender's File menu there is an Import submenu with Wavefront(.obj) as an option.  That should cover the importing.  I do not think there is a way in python to override the naming logic of that operation, so your best bet is to rename the objects after they have been successfully imported.